# realign yourself with somebody

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, definition

A learner's dictionary gives the following definition and sentence. Do you think the definition is accurate? It bothers me to find it different from other dictionaries' definitions, which don't contain the "again."

> realign yourself with somebody: to begin to support and work together with someone **again**:
>
> They have tried to realign themselves with the communists.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: What is it you don't understand about the prefix ***re-**?* You cite the definition ***realign** yourself with somebody: to begin to support and work together with someone **again***. And obviously there could be another definition ***align** yourself with somebody: to begin to support and work together with someone* (*without* the word ***again***). It's just like most other verbs - for example, you can't ***restate** your position* unless you've ***previously stated** your position*.

Comment: Oxford:
realign yourself (with somebody/something): to change your opinions, policies, etc. so that they are the same as those of another person, group, etc.

The rebel MPs have realigned themselves with the opposition party.

Cambridge:
realign yourself (with sb/sth): to change your ideas or policies so that they are the same as those of another person or group:

Several politicians left the party and realigned themselves with the opposition.

Comment: Oxford's and Cambridge's definitions do not contain "again" or its sense.

Comment: Well, all I can say is Cambridge define **align yourself with sth/sb** as *to agree with a person or an organization and work with them or support their ideas*, and they also define **realign yourself (with sb/sth)** as *to change your ideas or policies so that they are the same as those of another person or group*. There's a "clue" there, in that in order to ***change*** your ideas, you must have *previously* had some *different* ideas. It's just that over time, the "repeated" implication of prefix ***re-*** weakens with many verbs *(release, remove, resound,...)*.

Comment: Yes, so I believe re- as in "realign oneself with" simply implies change, not "again." The definition in the original post would lead to the unwanted entailment that they had previously supported the communists, changed their mind, before associating themselves with them again.

Comment: I think you're trying to impose a level of precision that English simply doesn't have in any "unambiguously, universally recognised" sense. I can't find your *specific* cited text anywhere except that dictionary example, so we have no context in which to interpret it. But I did find [*The Socialists, they feared, might realign themselves with the Communists...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22realign+themselves+with+the+communists%22) in Google Books. To me, it's an open question there whether *align **once again*** is implied, but historically Socialists *were* once thus aligned.

Comment: ...but here's an example where I think we've got to accept that pragmatically, "again" is strongly implied: [*If the young are removed from the barrel and left in an aquarium, they find their way back to the barrel, crawl along its external surface to an opening, crawl inside, and **realign** themselves with the other young.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22realign+themselves+with+the+other+young%22)

Comment: You posted a dictionary definition and ask if it is right. Well, good dictionaries are usually right, so what your point here?

Comment: Don't you see Longman's definition is inadequate in that it is too narrow?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Just to let you know, your comments on this question have been flagged again by users who feel they should be posted as answers instead.  Would you consider writing out an answer post instead?

Comment: @snailcar♦: Ho hum. I'm still trying to establish ***why*** the OP is so concerned about whether the specific word "again" should be included in a dictionary definition for "realign". Do the users complaining about me not posting Answers also complain about others doing the same? (Just so you know, it's starting to get on my tits! :~)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Indeed, I really think you should write a proper answer and enter it.

Comment: @Lambie: I don't really have much to add beyond what *you* commented. ***Good dictionaries are usually right, so what's your point here?***

Comment: My point was always that I've just been looking for an excuse to VTC as "vexatious" anyway. Is there really any point in arguing about whether ***repositioning** oneself [to take advantage of a situation* means something different to simply ***positioning** oneself?*

Comment: Apollyon, in this post, and in future posts, please include the source of the definition in question, and the definitions and sources you wish to compare. It will help clarify your point/problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two senses that we can interpret the `re-` prefix here; it is a morphological ambiguity.

`re-` definitely indicates that something is returning to a previous state or occurring again.  But what?   The problem is that alignment has two different denotations, both of which may apply in this sentence and mean the same thing!

1) alignment:  one's inclination or state of disposition.   The alignment of one's self is changing, one is realigning one's disposition.   That alignment happens to be compatible with the "somebody" of the definition in the question.  This is the sense that most commenters are taking.

2) alignment:  a correspondence or likeness of fit between two things.   The relationship between one's self and "somebody" is re-aligning; it was at some point before aligned, but has become unaligned, which we will now fix.  This is the sense the definition is taking.

The "again" is not implied by (1), but is by (2).  I would argue that (2) is the more correct interpretation of the sentence given in the definition, since the use of the preposition 'with' is awkward if we mean (1).

It's only a tiny difference however, and if the "again" mattered to the listener, s/he would almost certainly ask for clarification.

Comment: It's a huge difference. Consider this Cambridge example: _Several politicians left the party and realigned themselves with the opposition_.  If we plug Longman's definition into it, the original meaning would be arguably lost:

_Several politicians left the party and began to support and work together with the opposition **again**._  But if "realign oneself with . . ." simply implies change, there is no need to include "again" in the definition, and I suppose "instead" would work better if the spot had to be filled.

Comment: Yup.   This is exactly my point, and the example is not materially different than what's in the OP.   You're just arguing it's more than a tiny difference - I can certainly see your point, I guess.   It seems critical that the preposition contains a /who/ though:  compare with "I realigned my software with the correct specifications." where it could easily have either (1) or (2).  It's not just the "with", it's the "with" + person?

Answer (score 1):

*In writing this up I'm coming to realize that I think this is basically the same thing as what @BadZen already answered, but it took me a couple of readings of that answer to realize exactly what it was saying, so I'll add this additional answer in here in case it helps clarify things for anyone else*

There is actually some ambiguity here, because the phrase "realign with somebody" can be interpreted in two (similar but not quite the same) ways.

The verb **to align** can mean either:

- To set something's alignment / orientation to a particular value / position
- To cause something's alignment / orientation to match some specific other thing

The ambiguity comes in because the "particular value / position" could in fact also simultaneously "match some other thing", and in fact does in the case we're talking about, so it's a question of whether you interpret "align with somebody" to mean:

- "align" (Change one's alignment) to be "with somebody" (so that the new position is with somebody)

-or-

- "align with" (Change one's alignment to match) "somebody" (the alignment of "somebody" is thing you're matching)

Now, in the simple case of "align", the ambiguity isn't a big deal, because both of these mean the same thing, but when you add the "re-" prefix (meaning you are doing an action again that has been done before), the two don't actually have the same implications anymore:

- "realign" (Change one's alignment **again**) to be "with somebody" (so that the new position is with somebody)

> A started out aligned with B, but they realigned it with C later.

-or-

- "realign with" (Change one's alignment to match **again**) "somebody" (the alignment of "somebody" is thing you're matching)

> A was aligned with B, then it lost that alignment, but then later it was realigned with B.

In the first interpretation, it doesn't say anything about whether the alignment was ever "with somebody" before, it just says that it was previously aligned in some way, and you are realigning it in a different way, and that different way happens to now be "with somebody".  In the second interpretation, the implication is that it was previously "aligned with" somebody, and then somehow became different, and you are (again) changing the thing it's "aligned with" to be "somebody", like before.

To be clear:  Both of these are perfectly valid ways to interpret the statement.  There is no one always right or wrong answer here.  I think, in general, the only real way to know which meaning is intended is by the context it is used in.

Comment: I do say that the sense of use of the preposition makes (2) very much more probably the conveyed meaning, however - it's not completely neutral.